# Having different exception classes

Tags: c++, exception

I have a simple question about exceptions. Why is it the case that people frequently use separate classes for each type of exception, is it because we may want to handle different exceptions in different manner? (as compared to just catching "..." for instance).

Comment: yes....................

Comment: Not to mention it's easier to read and see what you handle going wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Exception objects are not just for indicating that something happened, so `catch (...)` would be a very primitive way to use the power of exceptions.

Each exception object will typically carry a "payload": information from the place where the exception occurred to the place where it is handled. As an exception flies up the unwinding call stack, the functions along the way might intercept it, enrich it with extra information and send it on its way further up. Different functional modules in the program will send completely different information to the exception handler, which is why you will need different exception classes to carry that information.

For example, parser exception might carry information about line number and nature of syntax error. File system exception might carry information about file name and error code. Dynamic memory exception might carry information about specific memory operation and memory block size. And so on. To store and carry those completely unrelated sets of data you'd normally define different exception types.

Comment: Ok, let's look at such approach. I have MyException class which inherits say from std::exception. Then, when I want to throw an exception, I say `throw(ID_OF_MY_ERROR)` - and then I have just one catch for all my exceptions, e.g., `catch (MyException e)` -- is this approach not enough?

Comment: @pseudonym_127: If this is enough for your application, then you don't even need any class. Just throw `int` or enum exceptions as error codes and that's it. But that would be like using a minuscule portion of full exception functionality. For those who want to use that full functionality this is definitely not enough. As I said, in many cases it is not enough to know the ID of the error. It is also necessary or desirable to know a potentionally large amount of additional information about the context of the error.

Comment: I meant `throw MyException(ID_OF_ERROR);`

Comment: @pseudonym_127: I understand. But again, if all you want to throw is an error ID, then you can just `throw ID_OF_ERROR`. No need for `MyException` at all.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to having different data to provide in exceptional cases and the different *manner* of handling different errors, you can also decide to handle them in different *places*. Consider a function `loadFileContentIntoMemory` that can throw errors due to file system errors (access rights, file not found etc.) and due to memory problems (typically `std::bad_alloc`). You might want to handle one kind of error while the other can not be handled at the same point. For example, you might want to catch file related errors and just try another filename, while it's normally hard to do anything about `bad_alloc` at any point of a program, so many programs catch it at a very top level location to issue an error message and terminate the program.